# Why when I want to create a new dataset in code below it works wrong when I use the the true algorithm

Tags: c

In my program I want to create a database. My `init_database` function is working correctly.
But I don't know why when I want to create more than one dataset they overwrite on each other when I use true algorithm. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS 50
#define MAX_NUM_OF_EXPRS 50
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100
enum directive {
    _dataset,   
    _delete_set,
    _insert_into,
    _delete_data,
    _select
};
enum type {
    _integer,
    _float,
    _string
};
union value{
    enum type _type;
    int int_val;
    float float_val;
    char* string_val;
};
struct attribute{
    char *name;
    union value val;
};
struct linked_data{
        struct linked_data* next;
        struct attribute attributes[MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS];
};
struct query {
    struct query *next_q;
    char target[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    enum directive q_type; 
    struct attribute expression[MAX_NUM_OF_EXPRS];
};
struct dataset{
    char *name;
    linked_data *data;
    dataset *next;
};
struct database{
    char *name;
    int size;
    dataset **table;
};
int hash(char *string,database *db){
    int flag=0,sum=0,code_number;
    while(string[flag]){
        sum=string[flag];
        flag++;
    }
    code_number=sum%(db->size);
    return code_number;
}
int str_size(char *string){
    int flag=0;
    while(string[flag]){
        flag++;
    }
    return flag;
}
 int init_database(database **db,int size,char *name){
     int size_str=str_size(name)+1;
     (*db)=(database *)malloc(sizeof(database));
     db[0]->table=(dataset**)malloc(sizeof(dataset *)*size);
     for(int counter=0;counter<size;counter++){
         db[0]->table[counter]=(dataset *)malloc(sizeof(dataset));
         db[0]->table[counter]->next=NULL;
     if(db[0]==NULL||(db[0]->table)==NULL||(db[0]->table[counter])==NULL)
            return 0;
     }
        db[0]->name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size_str);
        strcpy(db[0]->name,name);
        db[0]->name[size_str]=NULL;
        db[0]->size=size;
        return 1;
}
 int init_dataset(database *db,query *query){
     int hash_code=hash(query->target,db);
     int str_size1;
     dataset *prev;
     while(db->table[hash_code]){
         prev=db->table[hash_code];
         db->table[hash_code]=db->table[hash_code]->next;
     }
     db->table[hash_code]=(dataset*)malloc(sizeof(dataset));
     prev->next=db->table[hash_code];
     if(db->table[hash_code]==NULL)
             return 0;
     else{
        str_size1=str_size(query->target)+1;
        db->table[hash_code]->name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*str_size1);
        strcpy(db->table[hash_code]->name,"mohamad");
        db->table[hash_code]->next=NULL;
        return 1;
     }
 }
 int main(){
     database *db;
     query first_query;
     query second_query;
     strcpy(first_query.target,"mohamadreza");
     strcpy(second_query.target,"ahmad");
     init_database(&db,3,"ali");
     init_dataset(db,&first_query);
     init_dataset(db,&second_query);
 }
```

Comment: You are putting yourself into harms way with the enumeration names shown.  Many names starting with an underscore are reserved for the implementation — the fully nuanced story is more complex, but the simple version which only slightly overreaches is "names beginning with underscore are reserved", which means you should not use such names.

Comment: You must be compiling the code with a C++ compiler; it doesn't compile with a true C compiler.  This also explains the casts on `malloc()` which are necessary when you compile C code with a C++ compiler but which aren't necessary when you use a C compiler.  There are those who would castigate you mightily for the casts.  Which language are you learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the code is converted from C++ to C to match the question tag, and the warning about `prev` being uninitialized in `init_dataset()` is addressed by setting it to NULL and then asserting that it is not null before it is dereferenced, the code can be run under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) which diagnoses:

```
==5591== Invalid write of size 1
==5591==    at 0x100000D21: main (dbset.c:99)
==5591==  Address 0x10080a724 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==5591==    at 0x1000066F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==5591==    by 0x100000D16: main (dbset.c:97)
==5591== 
==5591== Invalid write of size 8
==5591==    at 0x100000BDB: init_dataset (dbset.c:124)
==5591==    by 0x100000D43: main (dbset.c:139)
==5591==  Address 0x10080a880 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 6 alloc'd
==5591==    at 0x1000066F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==5591==    by 0x100000BC7: init_dataset (dbset.c:123)
==5591==    by 0x100000D43: main (dbset.c:139)
```

The code is:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS 50
#define MAX_NUM_OF_EXPRS 50
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100

enum directive {
    _dataset,
    _delete_set,
    _insert_into,
    _delete_data,
    _select
};
enum type {
    _integer,
    _float,
    _string
};
union value
{
    enum type _type;
    int int_val;
    float float_val;
    char *string_val;
};
struct attribute
{
    char *name;
    union value val;
};
struct linked_data
{
    struct linked_data *next;
    struct attribute attributes[MAX_NUM_OF_ATTRS];
};
struct query
{
    struct query *next_q;
    char target[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    enum directive q_type;
    struct attribute expression[MAX_NUM_OF_EXPRS];
};
struct dataset
{
    char *name;
    struct linked_data *data;
    struct dataset *next;
};
struct database
{
    char *name;
    int size;
    struct dataset **table;
};

static
int hash(char *string, struct database *db)
{
    int flag = 0, sum = 0, code_number;
    while (string[flag])
    {
        sum = string[flag];
        flag++;
    }
    code_number = sum % (db->size);
    return code_number;
}

static
int str_size(char *string)
{
    int flag = 0;
    while (string[flag])
    {
        flag++;
    }
    return flag;
}

static
int init_database(struct database **db, int size, char *name)
{
    int size_str = str_size(name) + 1;
    (*db) = (struct database *)malloc(sizeof(struct database));
    db[0]->table = (struct dataset **)malloc(sizeof(struct dataset *) * size);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        db[0]->table[counter] = (struct dataset *)malloc(sizeof(struct dataset));
        db[0]->table[counter]->next = NULL;
        if (db[0] == NULL || (db[0]->table) == NULL || (db[0]->table[counter]) == NULL)
            return 0;
    }
    db[0]->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_str);
    strcpy(db[0]->name, name);
    db[0]->name[size_str] = '\0';
    db[0]->size = size;
    return 1;
}

static
int init_dataset(struct database *db, struct query *query)
{
    int hash_code = hash(query->target, db);
    int str_size1;
    struct dataset *prev = NULL;
    while (db->table[hash_code])
    {
        prev = db->table[hash_code];
        db->table[hash_code] = db->table[hash_code]->next;
    }
    db->table[hash_code] = (struct dataset *)malloc(sizeof(struct dataset));
    assert(prev != NULL);
    prev->next = db->table[hash_code];
    if (db->table[hash_code] == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        str_size1 = str_size(query->target) + 1;
        db->table[hash_code]->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * str_size1);
        strcpy(db->table[hash_code]->name, "mohamad");
        db->table[hash_code]->next = NULL;
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct database *db;
    struct query first_query;
    struct query second_query;
    strcpy(first_query.target, "mohamadreza");
    strcpy(second_query.target, "ahmad");
    init_database(&db, 3, "ali");
    init_dataset(db, &first_query);
    init_dataset(db, &second_query);
}
```

The line numbers and function identifications are a bit funny because of the `static` qualifiers I placed on the functions which means GCC (4.9.1, running on Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite) has inlined the code.

```
 97     db[0]->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_str);
 98     strcpy(db[0]->name, name);
 99     db[0]->name[size_str] = '\0';
```

You've allocated an array of `size_str` bytes; that means the indexes run from `0` to `size_str-1`.  In any case, `strcpy()` null terminated the string, so line 99 should simply be deleted.

```
122         str_size1 = str_size(query->target) + 1;
123         db->table[hash_code]->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * str_size1);
124         strcpy(db->table[hash_code]->name, "mohamad");
```

Here, you've allocated enough space for `query->target`, but you copy `"mohamad"` over it.  The size of 6 in the error message means this must be for the call to `init_dataset()` with `"ahmad"` as the name.  The fix is to copy the name passed as an argument rather than the fixed name:

```
122         str_size1 = str_size(query->target) + 1;
123         db->table[hash_code]->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * str_size1);
124         strcpy(db->table[hash_code]->name, query->target);
```

You have some residual memory leaks.  The Mac OS X runtime also 'leaks' (does not free) quite a lot of memory, but a full analysis shows that a couple of the reported leakages are your problem rather than the system's problem:

```
==5668== 60 (24 direct, 36 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 41 of 89
==5668==    at 0x1000066F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==5668==    by 0x100000CD9: main (dbset.c:92)
==5668== 
==5668== 130 (24 direct, 106 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 56 of 89
==5668==    at 0x1000066F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==5668==    by 0x100000CB8: main (dbset.c:88)
```

Line 88:

```
88     (*db) = (struct database *)malloc(sizeof(struct database));
```

Line 92:

```
92         db[0]->table[counter] = (struct dataset *)malloc(sizeof(struct dataset));
```

There was one other (not yet suppressed) leak, but that was categorically not your problem.

Without suppressions:

```
==5836== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5836==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 3 blocks
==5836==    indirectly lost: 142 bytes in 8 blocks
==5836==      possibly lost: 13,130 bytes in 120 blocks
==5836==    still reachable: 21,829 bytes in 307 blocks
==5836==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

With suppressions:

```
==5837== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5837==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==5837==    indirectly lost: 142 bytes in 8 blocks
==5837==      possibly lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==5837==    still reachable: 21,829 bytes in 307 blocks
==5837==         suppressed: 13,122 bytes in 120 blocks
```

The 'possibly lost' bytes are not your problem.

Answer (score 1):

- dataset *prev in method init_dataset is not allocated memory;
- in method init_dataset you have hard coded the table name as "mohamad". Shouldn't this be replaced with query->target?
- in method init_dataset your call to hash is returning the same index for both table names. It does not look like you accounted for collision in your hash table when generating the hash value. Please refer to this article for further explanation of what I am referring to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution